# Laravel getting Posts based on Roles of users

Tags: php, laravel

in my database structure each `Category` belongs to a user or multiple `Users`, each user belongs to a `Role` or multiple roles, and then each user have a `Post` or multiple posts which this model belongs to `Category`,

**tip:** `Category` not belongs to `Role` model

simply we can get posts or categories from this structure but i want to get all posts based on users specific `role` and fetching this posts belong to which categories

my implemented code is not correct and that return empty list:

```
$posts = Category::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->with(['user'=>function($q){
        $q->with(['roles'=>function($u){
            $u->whereLabel('is-admin');
        }]);
    },'posts']);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

I've tested the second solution and it seems to be working just fine. I did bring one minor change; that is change `categories` to `category`. Here is the updated code:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('user.roles', function($q){
    return $q->whereLabel('is-admin');
})->with('category')->get();
```

I assumed your relationship definitions to be similar to the following (showing only the necessary relations):

*Note before: Role and User has a many to many relationship because one user can have many roles and one role can belong to many users. Therefore a pivot table role_user sits between roles and users table to manage user roles.*

In user model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Role model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Post Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

---

Basically user hasMany roles, and category doesn't have anything to do with roles, and in this situation nothing to do with users either. so why not try selecting posts based on user roles and then eager load categories. Give this a try:

```
Post::with(['user.roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereLabel('is-admin');
}])->with('categories')->get();
//OR
Post::whereHas('user.roles', function ($query) {
    $query->whereLabel('is-admin');
})->with('categories')->get();
```

Comment: and there is another things, first query return all `posts` and couldn't specify or filter by role, it means i have all posts and roles, this roles maybe is into relation ship, can i have only filtered list by specific role? thanks in advance

Comment: I would have thought the second one to be the one to work. Let me test this.

Comment: Tested and the second one is in fact working, please check the updated answer.